# Calculating change in column over groups and extracting based on criteria

Tags: c#, difference, u-sql, windowing

I am a beginner to coding in U-SQL/C#. I am stuck in a place during windowing/aggregation.

My Data looks like

```
Name          Date                  OrderNo    Type   Balance
one 2018-06-25T04:55:44.0020987Z      1        Drink     15       
one 2018-06-25T04:57:44.0020987Z      1        Drink     70      
one 2018-06-25T04:59:44.0020987Z      1        Drink     33       
one 2018-06-25T04:59:49.0020987Z      1        Drink     25       
two 2018-06-25T04:55:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     22       
two 2018-06-25T04:57:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     81       
two 2018-06-25T04:58:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     33       
two 2018-06-25T04:59:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     45
```

In U-SQL I am adding a unique id based on combinations of name, orderno and type and for the purpose of sorting, I am adding another one including the date.

```
@files = 
EXTRACT
        name string,
        date DateTime,
        type string,
        orderno int,
        balance int           
FROM
@InputFile
USING new JsonExtractor();

@files2 =
    SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY name,type,orderno,date) AS group_id,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY name,type,orderno) AS id
     FROM @files;
```

My Data now looks like this:

```
Name          Date                  OrderNo    Type   Balance group_id id
one 2018-06-25T04:55:44.0020987Z      1        Drink     15       1     1
one 2018-06-25T04:57:44.0020987Z      1        Drink     70       2     1
one 2018-06-25T04:59:44.0020987Z      1        Drink     33       3     1
one 2018-06-25T04:59:49.0020987Z      1        Drink     25       4     1
two 2018-06-25T04:55:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     22       5     2
two 2018-06-25T04:57:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     81       6     2
two 2018-06-25T04:58:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     33       7     2
two 2018-06-25T04:59:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     45       8     2
```

(I have added only 4 records per group but there are multiple per group)

I am stuck at determining the **difference** between successive rows in the **balance** column in **each group**.

Expected Output for Part 1:

```
Name          Date                  OrderNo    Type   Balance group_id id  increase
one 2018-06-25T04:55:44.0020987Z      1        Drink     15       1     1    0
one 2018-06-25T04:57:44.0020987Z      1        Drink     70       2     1    55
one 2018-06-25T04:59:44.0020987Z      1        Drink     33       3     1   -37
one 2018-06-25T04:59:49.0020987Z      1        Drink     25       4     1   -8
two 2018-06-25T04:55:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     22       5     2    0
two 2018-06-25T04:57:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     81       6     2    59
two 2018-06-25T04:58:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     33       7     2   -48
two 2018-06-25T04:59:44.0020987Z      2        Drink     45       8     2    8
```

For every new group (defined by id) the increase should start from zero.

I went through stack overflow and saw the lag function from transgresql. I could not find a C# equivalent. Is that applicable in this case?

Any help is appreciated. Further clarification will be provided if required.

Update: When I use CASE WHEN my solution looks like this

```
CURRENT OUTPUT                            DESIRED OUTPUT
id Balance Increase                     id  Balance Increase
 1  15      0                            1  15      0
 1  70     55                            1  70     55
 1  33    -37                            1  33    -37
 1  25     -8                            1  25     -8
 2  22    "-3"                           2  22     "0"
 2  81     59                            2  81     59
 2  33    -48                            2  33    -48
 2  45     12                            2  45     12
```

Look at the highlighted row. The increase column must start at 0 for each id.

Update: I was able to solve the first part of my question. See my answer below. 
The second part that I had posted earlier was incorrectly posted. I have removed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that finally worked for me was this..

```
@files = 
EXTRACT
        name string,
        date DateTime,
        type string,
        orderno int,
        balance int           
FROM
@InputFile
USING new JsonExtractor();

@files2 =
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY name,type,orderno) AS group_id
FROM @files;

@files3 =
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY date) AS group_order
FROM @files2;


@files4 =
SELECT *,
     (CASE WHEN group_order == 1 THEN 0 
         ELSE  balance  - LAG(balance) OVER(ORDER BY name,type,orderno) 
    END) AS increase 
FROM @files3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/lag-u-sql) window function get previous `Balance` in a subquery, then use `where` write the condition.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY name,type,orderno,date) AS group_id,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY name,type,orderno) AS id,
       (CASE WHEN LAG(Balance) OVER(ORDER BY name,type,orderno) IS NULL THEN 0 
             ELSE  Balance  - LAG(Balance) OVER(ORDER BY name,type,orderno) 
        END) as increase 
    FROM @files
) t1
WHERE increase > 50
```

Comment: The result looks almost good except for each new group, the value does not start from 0. Including the first record. The value starts from 50 in first id group and from -3 in second id group.

Comment: Maybe something to do with running query over each id group systematically in one shot and then skipping the first rows would do the trick. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Interested_Programmer I edit my answer you can try it, use `CASE WHEN`

Comment: I have updated the question with what your code produces. It is close but not exact to my desired output. The focus on that output is because I have thousands of ids and for each row neglecting the first row is hard.

Comment: Look at my answer. It produced the necessary output for first part of my question. Thanks for suggesting CASE WHEN.